# pandas dataframe to json with each row encapsulated in a parent element

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'd like to use the to_json() function to serialize a pandas dataframe while encapsulating each row in a root 'Person' element.

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['tom', 10], ['nick', 15], ['juli', 14]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age'])
df.to_json(orient='records')
'[{"Name":"tom","Age":10},{"Name":"nick","Age":15},{"Name":"juli","Age":14}]'
```

I'd like the to_json() output to be:

```
'[{"Person":{"Name":"tom","Age":10}},{"Person":{"Name":"nick","Age":15}},{"Person":{"Name":"juli","Age":14}}]'
```

I'm thinking this can be achieved with dataframe.apply() but haven't been able to figure it out.

Thx.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`List Comprehension`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp) to create a list of `dicts` using [`df.to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

```
In [4370]: d = [{'Person':i} for i in df.to_dict(orient='records')]
```

Convert above `dict` to json using  [`json.dumps`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/json-dumps-in-python/):

```
In [4372]: import json

In [4373]: j = json.dumps(d)

In [4374]: print(j)
Out[4373]: '[{"Person": {"Name": "tom", "Age": 10}}, {"Person": {"Name": "nick", "Age": 15}}, {"Person": {"Name": "juli", "Age": 14}}]'
```

Comment: @user14757480 Did the answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to use `Person` as an index or identifier for each set. Otherwise, just include `Person` as a fixed string key for each nested `dict` would be redundant. If this is the case, you can use `index` inside the `orient` argument. In this case, it would append the index associated with the data frame.

```
import pandas as pd
>>> data = [['tom', 10], ['nick', 15], ['juli', 14]]
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age'])
>>> temp = [df.to_json(orient='index')]
>>> temp = ['{"0":{"Name":"tom","Age":10},"1":{"Name":"nick","Age":15},"2":{"Name":"juli","Age":14}}']
```

Also, you can adjust your `index` to whatever you want. I hope this is what you want.